# Javascript - synchronize 2 arrays of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, synchronization

For example, I have two arrays of objects

```
[
 {
   'id':1,
   'value':'someval for id 1',
   'score':1     
 },
 {
   'id':2,
   'value':'someval for id 2 with score 2',
   'score':2     
 },
 {
   'id':4,
   'value':'someval for id 2',
   'score':1     
 }
]
```

and

```
[
 {
   'id':2,
   'value':'someval for id 2 ',
   'score':1     
 },
 {
   'id':3,
   'value':'someval for id 3',
   'score':1     
 }
]
```

I want to synchronize both of them to be like this

```
[
 {
   'id':1,
   'value':'someval for id 1',
   'score':1     
 },
 {
   'id':2,
   'value':'someval for id 2 with score 2',
   'score':2     
 },
 {
   'id':3,
   'value':'someval for id 3',
   'score':1     
 },
 {
   'id':4,
   'value':'someval for id 2',
   'score':1     
 }
]
```

so, i want the sync to work on this rules

1. if item with id is not present in one of arrays, it is copied from array where is is present
2. if two items have the same id, we keep the one with higher score

Is there any libraries or node modules, that can do this synchronization for quite big arrays (nodejs modules preferred)?

Where shall i start my research to make this function in proper way?

Comment: Are the two arrays always sorted by `id` like that ? and how big they can be ?

Comment: no, not sorted, but they can be sorted if we need it. The array size is from 1000 to 10000 elements, also all this code have to be executed in nodejs, not in browser...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an off the shelf module to accomplish this, but Underscore provides some good utility functions on arrays and collections that would make your code easier to write.  Seems like some combination of zip, group by, and max would do the trick.

http://underscorejs.org/